# Add a custom validation in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working with a nested model a question has multiple answers and only one can be marked as  correct how can i validate to check that only one question was marked as correct. The correct is a boolean field.

```
#question model
validate :one_correct_answers

  def one_correct_answers
    if self.choices.correct_choices > 1
      errors.add(:base, "please select only one correct answer")
    end
  end
```

Comment: what about using radio buttons in view...

Comment: the answers are added dynamically in the view so a radio button will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Question model

```
class Question
  has_many :choices
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :choices, :reject_if => ->(choice){ choice[:value].blank? }
  validate :only_one_correct_answer

  private
  def only_one_correct_answer
    unless (choices.select{ |choice| choice.correct }.size == 1)
      errors.add(:choices, "You must provide only 1 correct answer")
   end
  end
end
```

In Form HTML

```
<input name="question[choices_attributes][0][correct]" type="checkbox">
<input name="question[choices_attributes][1][correct]" type="checkbox">
<input name="question[choices_attributes][2][correct]" type="checkbox">
<input name="question[choices_attributes][3][correct]" type="checkbox"> ... till n
```

and in QuestionsController

```
@question = Question.new(params[:question])
@question.valid? => will automatically call Question#only_one_correct_answer and add errors,if any.
```

I hope, this will help you. :)

Comment: this works fine. Initially i used an after_save method and ran thesame query in my question and it worked fine i also but its kinda slow.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, your checkboxes should look like this:

```
<input id="something_" name="something[]" type="checkbox" value="<%= some_id %>">
```

This way, when you submit the form, the params should look like and array of the checked checkboxes:

```
params: something => [1, 2]
```

Then, on your controller you set the variable `correct_choices` to this array, and validate with your custom validator.